# Resizing custom markers in Leaflet for R

Tags: r, leaflet

I am interested in making custom icons while using Leaflet in R.

The [documentation](http://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/markers.html) has a nice example, but when experimenting with it, I realized that there is no way to allow the custom marker to resize when the map changes size.

Since size is one of the parameters and is fixed (`iconWidth = 38, iconHeight = 95,`), obviously the marker will stay consistently sized as zoom changes for map beneath it.

```
greenLeafIcon <- makeIcon(
  iconUrl = "http://leafletjs.com/docs/images/leaf-green.png",
  iconWidth = 38, iconHeight = 95,
  iconAnchorX = 22, iconAnchorY = 94,
  shadowUrl = "http://leafletjs.com/docs/images/leaf-shadow.png",
  shadowWidth = 50, shadowHeight = 64,
  shadowAnchorX = 4, shadowAnchorY = 62
)
```

Are there any hacks / ideas / protocols for having custom icons resize along with zoom?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17382012/is-there-a-way-to-resize-marker-icons-depending-on-zoom-level-in-leaflet

Comment: That question is for Leaflet in JavaScript as opposed to the package written in R.

Comment: the package in R wraps the Leaflet JavaScript and that solution is what you'll need to do to modify the size. You can add arbitrary JS functions to an R leaflet map.

Comment: So my question should have been, 'How do I wrap JavaScript code in R such that I can use it in the Leaflet package to resize my custom markers'! :-)

Comment: Still no solution for the R package?